# How to filter a text file in a batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file names `ImageList.txt` with a list of filenames:

```
file1.jpg
file1.dip
file2.jpg
file3.dip
```

I have to get just `.jpg` filenames and call another script with the name of that file.

Something like:

```
for (thisFile:ImageList.txt) call AdjustRatio.cmd(thisFile)
```

How to do that in a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me as if this task is better done using the `findstr.exe` utility.

[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```py
For /F Delims^= %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /EIL ".jpg" "ImageList.txt"') Do @Call "AdjustRatio.cmd" "%G"
```

[batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```bsh
@For /F Delims^= %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /EIL ".jpg" "ImageList.txt"') Do @Call "AdjustRatio.cmd" "%%G"
```

Answer (score 0):

well i found a solution by myself
if ever somebody else will need to do the same thing, here it is

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("ImageList.txt") do call :check %%A

:check
set f=%1
set ext=%f:~-4%
if "%ext%" equ ".jpg" echo %f%
```

Comment: `... do if /i "%~xA" == ".jpg" echo %%A` See `for /?`, especially the "modifiers" section.

Answer (score 0):

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %%G in (imagelist.txt) Do If "%%~xG" == ".jpg" Echo/%%G
```

No need to `call` a function or execute `findstr` to test the extension, just use the for variable modifier `~x` to get the extension, and an `If` condition to perform whatever action on the desired match.